# SQL Server 2008 upgrade to 2016 causing error due to the use of reserved word (External) in locked .exe, can't change SQL

Tags: sql-server

We have a third party windows app that we don't have the code for (and supplier doesn't exist anymore), this app connects to SQL Server database (originally 2008R2). We now need this app to connect (and run against) a SQL Server 2016 database.

The problem is the app fires SQL commands into the database with queries that contain reserved words (i.e. it alias a table AS External) which causes the SQL Server 2016 server to error.

Does anybody know of a setting / trick / workaround that we could employ so that the 2016 server will accept the offending query?

We can't change the actual query as it's in the .exe

edit .... The old server was SQL 2008 , not SQL 2008 R2

Comment: Even in SQL Server 2008 `EXTERNAL` was a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms189822\(v=sql.100\)) (and in [2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms189822\(v=sql.90\))).

Comment: you can probably find the strings in the exe file

Comment: @ThomA I'd assume the compat level was lower though

Comment: Yep, guessing it was set to compat 2000, @Charlieface . Suggests that the application the user is using hasn't been updated in 18 years... Perhaps it *shouldn't* be used any more. /shrug

Comment: And even SQL Server 2016 is no longer in mainstream support. I'm not sure what answer is expected. Delaying upgrades for 18 years (since 2005) will inevitably lead to exactly this problem. This isn't a technical question. t's high time the *application* itself was replaced. Or you'll have to keep using an 15-year old unsupported system